# Bootstrap Tabs Not Letting me change ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Alright, I am building an application that has Bootstrap Tabs. I have all the .js files that Twitter Bootstrap has to offer in my head tag.

When I add tabs like this it works

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Post Update</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Post Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Post Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">Create a Poll</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">Test 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">Test 2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">Test 3</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">Test 4</div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#myTab a:last').tab('show');
    });
</script>
```

But on the other hand, when I change the ID on the tabs in my JavaScript and HTML, it does not work any more...

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" id="changedID">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Post Update</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Post Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Post Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">Create a Poll</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">Test 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">Test 2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">Test 3</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">Test 4</div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#changedID a:last').tab('show');
    });
</script>
```

Is there any way to fix this issue with bootstrap tabs, because this will get really annoying if I cannot put more than one set of tabs on the same page.

Comment: did you change the `a`'s href too?

Comment: Just a guess, but are you duplicating IDs somewhere? Check for multiple instances of `changedID` and / or `tab1` through `tab4`

Comment: Works for me: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regisc/KqpmJ/)

Comment: @RC. Did you actually try clicking on the tabs? It doesn't appear to work

Comment: @Phil is does not work on his fiddle because he has just bound the tabbing to one anchor tag. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/achakravarty/DGvxs/

Comment: Did you read the documentation regarding using JavaScript to activate tabs? [*each tab needs to be activated individually*](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage). @achakravarty Yup, just noticed that :)

Comment: Sorry @RC., that was directed at the OP :)

Comment: I saw that on there, but I was not sure what it actually meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding data-toggle="tab" to your links, and make sure your second set of tabs on the page have different id's

http://jsfiddle.net/JqGt9/1/

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Post Update</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Post Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Post Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Create a Poll</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">Test 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">Test 2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">Test 3</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">Test 4</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab2">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Post Update</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab">Post Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab7" data-toggle="tab">Post Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab8" data-toggle="tab">Create a Poll</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab5">Test 5</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab6">Test 6</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab7">Test 7</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab8">Test 8</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought it was kinda weird, I could use one id for the tabs, but not another id..

Comment: Truth is, the id on the .nav-tabs is somewhat irrelevant. The real key is the unique id for each .tab-pane. More than one instance of an id on a page can have unpredictable effects.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this format.

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
<li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
<p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
<p> I'm in Section 2.</p>
</div>
</div>


----------
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
})
```